# Bootstrap alert modal without HTML

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

A very simple problem, but surprisingly, can't find any answers.

I am looking to alert something in the browser, very similar to

```
alert('please try again');
```

I want to use bootstrap for this, I tried this

```
$("#div-alert").html("please try again");
$("#div-alert").modal('show');
```

This does not work, no modal shows up.

I don't want to use any HTML here, just javascript. I know there are other alert systems like `swal` but I want to use bootstrap only.

Comment: Well, you'll have to construct the html with javascript and insert it into the DOM then... which I'm pretty sure will be more trouble than just adding a few lines of html with the proper classes. That said, what is `#div-alert`? Is it a proper bootstrap modal already?

Comment: No, I don't want to dive into HTML, I don't have priveleges to do that, just want to show an alert modal in bootstrap

Comment: No, it's not a bootstrap modal already, I need to make it a modal maybe by adding a class for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the modal element dynamically in your JS/JQuery if you wish.

After creating it, you'll need to add an event to an existing element (like a button or some event listener) that will trigger the modal to show up.

Something along the lines of:

```js
$(function() {
  var modalHtml =
    ' <div class="modal-content">' +
    '   <div class="modal-body">' +
    '      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">' +
    '        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>' +
    '      </button>' +
    '      <strong>Oh snap!</strong> Change a few things up and try submitting again.' +
    '   </div>' + 
    ' </div>';

  // clicking on the button triggers the modal 
  $("button.btn").on('click', function() {
    // insert HTML dynamically
    $(".modal-dialog").html(modalHtml);
    // display
    $(".modal-dialog").modal('show');
  });

  // append a new element to the DOM
  $("button").after('<div class="modal-dialog modal"></div>');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
  Show Modal
</button>
<!-- Modal will be added here -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the alert and the modal in the bootstrap. Try the following snippet.

Step 1 - Include the bootstrap cdn or download their files and insert them to your html
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Step 2 - Refer the bootstrap modal and alert 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/alerts/

Assume you are using bootstrap 4 in this scenario.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Alert with Modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
      <strong>Oh snap!</strong> Change a few things up and try submitting again.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP does not have the permissions to add/modify any HTML.  Wants to do it all via JS... adding HTML for the modal in Bootstrap does not seem like a solution to OP

Comment: So you can add all html parts inside a javascript right?

Comment: that's not what your answer does, right?